# How to uninstall spf13 Vim distribution?

Tags: python, macos, vim, macvim

I'm using MacVim in Mountain Lion I've installed spf13 Vim distribution but when I type`:set ft=python` MacVim suddenly crash so I want to uninstall it and try Janus. I've install it typing  `curl https://j.mp/spf13-vim3 -L > spf13-vim.sh && sh spf13-vim.sh` in the terminal. How can I do that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm sorry you haven't had success with the distribution. If :set ft=python is crashing your vim it's definitely due to an incompatibility between the python plugins we use and the python environment VIM is running with. This isn't uncommon, it's one of the disadvantages of using an external language in vim plugins, you can't control the environment and often there are incompatibilities across different python (or ruby) versions. While this is likely not your specific issue, this link highlights these problems http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.editors.vim/98903.

You may have more success with Janus, it's a good distribution, but very ruby focused and heavily dependent on ruby. You would likely be better off ensuring that your python environment is what you expect since this isn't a distribution problem, but a problem with one of the python plugins which you presumably would want since you are editing python. I would suggest disabling the python plugins until you find the problematic one. There are only 4 listed at https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim/blob/3.0/.vimrc.bundles#L172.

I would also encourage you to [file an issue](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim/issues) and [email the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/spf13-vim-discuss). There is a large community that would likely be able to help.

To uninstall spf13-vim:

Download and run https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim/blob/3.0/uninstall.sh
or simply follow along with the commands in that file.

Comment: If I have some time I will try to find the error! Thanks a lot for the help and to try to make Vim more easy!

Answer (score 13):

I simply used this:

```
sh .spf13-vim-3/uninstall.sh
```

Answer (score 3):

As much as I hate the SPF13 distribution (and all the others), the crash is *not* caused by SPF13 but most probably by some Python-related plugin that comes with SPF13. Maybe because of discrepancies between Python versions.

Anyway, the author of SPF13 is responsible of the mess that is created by his distribution, maybe he can tell you if and where he wrote anything outside of `~/.vim/`. Maybe that's in the doc. In the meantime,

```
$ mv ~/.vim/ ~/.spf13_vim
$ mv ~/.vimrc ~/.spf138vimrc
```

should move all traces of that SPF13 crap out of sight.

You should grab that chance to take control of your configuration and *not* install Janus or any other damn distribution.

Comment: Thanks it worked! I think I'm NOT up to Vim! I've tried with a post in the spf12 google group now I will try to file an issue. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Take it easy @romaini - even though distributions of vim aren't your thing you can still be civil...